Two profiles or permission sets and limiting access to one SSO or the other. Possible?
We use Cloud Access Management (CAM) for our SSO. Is it possible to configure two CAM SSO profiles and have that assigned to different sets of users so that User A for instance is given CAM SSO profile 1 and user B is given CAM SSO profile 2. The idea here is that users are only able to SSO using the URL they are assigned and get blocked if they use other url. Yes a longer term fix is to change the implementation but seeing what capabilities Salesforce allows us.
Is this possible?
Use case needed:
We are using Cam SSO that passes a URL to SSO that sets MFA flag to true and as the current implementation stands, it is an all or nothing in terms of MFA (CAM IBM stack for IWA based SSO flows).

The issue is that some of our users cannot do MFA as they are offshore and don't have phones.

We were hoping to have two SAML configs under Single sign on (with their own urls) in salesforce and using permission sets send them to either the MFA = true Url or the MFA = false url to SSO. Salesforce provides multi SAML configs and we are just trying to determine how to select one or the other based on permission set or profiles.

What's the purpose of this configuration?

In general, a request to login to your mydomain will have SFDC route the request to the identity provider that in turn provides a SAML assertion back to SFDC that SFDC checks against the federation Id or username.  Why would users have different URLs to login? Do you have two SFDC orgs?

@sfdcfox I added details to the answer.

@cropredy Same org but one URL will have MFA=true, and other MFA=false. I guess how does one select a SAML config for the user in question based on their permission set or profile. Sorry if this seems like a convoluted ask.

Can the offshore users use security keys or built-in authenticators (e.g. Windows Hello, Mac TouchId) - see MFA options

@cropredy unfortunately not but I will check with our team. I guess the question is we have multi SAML configs in Salesforce, how to select one programmatically based on user permission and role.

How about: If you create two Identity providers, then each can be added to the login page. Call one Domestic, the other Offshore.  Users would click the relevant one (of course a domestic user could click Offshore and bypass MFA though perhaps a login flow could detect this and throw an error. But it seems odd that anyone these days can't be set up with an MFA device (security key or biometric) if they don't have phone.
